# Craft plugin services in subfolders

Tags: php, craft-features, controller, services

So I'm getting to a point where I have a lot of services in a particular plugin, and I would like to organize my plugin services into sub-folders. I've tried a couple ways but the controllers don't seem to be able to find the appropriate services unless they are in the main services directory. I know I can put controller files in sub-folders of the controllers folder, so I thought the same would be true for services. Does Craft support what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Craft will only look in the immediate `pluginHandle/services` folder when auto-loading and registering a plugin's service files.

If you wanted to support services in subfolders (i.e. `pluginhandle/services/subfolder1`, etc.), you'd have to manually autoload and register those classes yourself from your plugin's `init()` method.